# Form not submitting after AJAX call returns true

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm using Google Phone validation library to check if a number is valid with an AJAX call.  If the number isn't valid, I need the below function to prevent the form from submitting.

Currently it prevents the form from submitting correctly, but the form doesn't submit when it returns true.  The alert at the true statement does indeed occur, but the form still doesn't submit.  What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form#sellerForm').submit(validatePhoneNumber);
});

function validatePhoneNumber() {
var output = null;
var phoneNumber = $('#phone').val();
var node = document.getElementById('phoneOutput');
var country = $('#country').val();
if(country == -1){
  output = translateNoCountry();
  node.innerHTML = output;
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
if(output == null){
  //AJAX to get country code from country for var regionCode;
  $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
    url: '/ajax/validate_phone.php', 
    data: {country: country},
    cache: false, 
    success: function(result) {
    var regionCode = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
      try {
        var phoneUtil = i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
        var number = phoneUtil.parseAndKeepRawInput(phoneNumber, regionCode);
        var isNumberValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(number);
        if(!isNumberValid){//invalid number
            output = translateInvalidePhone();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        output = translateInvalidePhone();
      }
    if(output != null){
        node.innerHTML = output;
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }else{
        alert('Hello world');
        return true;
    }
}
});
event.preventDefault();
return false;
}
}
```

Comment: you have return false; at the end. ..try to define function out side of document ready

Comment: As an aside, you can say `$('form#sellerForm').submit(validatePhoneNumber);` - you don't need the anonymous wrapper function if the only thing it does is call your named function. Regarding your actual problem, hint: Ajax is _asynchronous._

Comment: @nnnnnn may be OP wants to send events in function args so OP used that method..

Comment: @DipeshParmar - jQuery already does that - notice the anonymous function also has `events` as its only explicitly declared argument.

Comment: @nnnnnn i know may be OP don't know that's why i said that...sorry

Comment: I'll fix it up to be a little more clear.

Comment: The weird part as I said, it returns 'Hello world' where it should at that alert, but doesn't submit even though it should return true.

Answer (score 1):

What is the use of,

```
event.preventDefault();
return false;
```

in the last line. I think it could be the problem.

Comment: If the line is removed, than the form submits without going through the AJAX call.  So it submits for errors also.

Comment: @vinsanity38 you can prevent the default action in the beginning itself.

Comment: I only want the default action to be prevented if it fails the function though

Answer (score 0):

don't use event.preventDefault(); at very last of your validatePhoneNumber() function

it prevent all the default postbacks